# How do I clear the SharedPreferences or other permanent storage of my Android app from my app program?

Tags: android, mobile-application

I need to retain some information so that I can access it when I launch my app after it is closed. I need to use that information on 'onCreate()' of my 'MainActivity'. But I need to clear/reset those information if the mobile is rebooted. So how do I know in the program if the mobile has been rebooted and the activity is launched for the first time after reboot?

Answer (score 6):

Listen for the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast to know when the phone has been turned on.

Then use `SharedPreferences.Editor.clear()` followed by a `commit()` to delete all data for your app.

Comment: Does BOOT_COMPLETED work with phones like Huawei Honor?

Comment: It should, but you won't know for sure till you try. I don't think it's very common for devices to not send that broadcast, however